# Ruby: Prepend info to exception messages without touching stacktrace

Tags: ruby, exception

I need to prepend debugging info to all exceptions that occur within a block, but I don't want to mess up the backtrace.`$!` doesn't seem to be allowing this in 1.9.3; `raise` is replacing the backtrace regardless of what I try.

Ideas?

Here's what I was using originally:

```
def self.load(filename, virtual_path = nil)
  t = Template.new(filename, virtual_path)
  t.is_page? ? Page.new(t) : t
rescue
  raise $!, "Error loading template '#{filename}'#{virtual_path ? " under virtual path '" + virtual_path  + "'" : ""}: #{$!}"
end
```

The best I've found so far is this:

```
def self.load(filename, virtual_path = nil)
  t = Template.new(filename, virtual_path)
  t.is_page? ? Page.new(t) : t
rescue => e
    raise e, "Error loading template '#{filename}'#{virtual_path ? " under virtual path '" + virtual_path  + "'" : ""}: #{e.message} #{e.backtrace}"
end
```

**This dumps the original stack trace into the message, but still doesn't preserve the old stack trace as the stack trace**

Comment: Whatever you tried post in your description, which in turn help us to suggest you something better.

Comment: I've updated the question with examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [Kernel#raise](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) method, it can take three parameters:

```
raise(exception [, string [, array]])
```

If you want to keep the backtrace, you should specify the `array` parameter, which is the callback information.

**Example:**

Say you originally had:

```
def some_method()
    raise('original message')
end

some_method
#=> scratch.rb:10:in `some_method': original message (RuntimeError)
#   from scratch.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

You can use the third parameter of the exception to raise a new exception with updated message and the same backtrace:

```
def some_method()
    begin
        raise('error message')
    rescue
        raise $!, 'new message', $!.backtrace
    end
end

some_method
#=> scratch.rb:10:in `some_method': new message (RuntimeError)
#       from scratch.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

As you can see, the new exception is the same as the original exception, except with the updated message.